# What is different between "?" and ":username" in PDO?

Tags: php, pdo

I have syntax like this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE username = ?";
$username = "foo";
$stmt->execute(array($username));
```

and

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE username = :username";
$params = array(":username"=>"foo");
$stmt->execute($params);
```

Comment: First one relies on order of the values to fill in the `?`s. Second one the order in the array doesn't matter.

Comment: @Rio Could you please stop posting questions asking for language tutoring or as manual reading substitute?

Comment: Aw @mario, be nice `:-)`. I agree the OP could search for these questions first (so a close vote is justified) but otherwise, it was a good, clear question.

Answer (score 3):

<s>there is no difference</s>

`:username` one is just a syntax sugar supported by PDO, it gets internally substituted either with literal `?` or escaped data depends on the settings (`PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` one)

It is a widely spread belief that named placeholders are more readable. However, in my opinion they only make code unnecessarily bloated while adding no readability at all. Repeating the same field name for half a dozen times doesn't make code readable. if you have more than 3-5 placeholders in the query - it's time to think of some automation, a loop for exapmle.

As `sachleen` pointed out in the comments, the only difference is possible order of bound data.

With regular `?` placeholders you have to follow strict order, while with named placeholders you can bind them in any order:

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT name FROM table WHERE name=? AND age=?");
$stm->execute(array($name,$age)); // strict order matching one in the query
```

but

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT name FROM table WHERE name=:name AND age=:age");
$stm->execute(array(":age"=>$age,":name"=>$name)); // whatever order
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the internal substitution breaks one of the advantages of name-based place-holders: you cannot reliably repeat parameters. This PDO restriction is not present in other DB libraries.

Comment: I gave you +1 before you added the last paragraph about readability. I'm tempted to remove the +1 (I won't, but I'm tempted), because you've completely missed one of the main selling points of using named placeholders -- it means that the parameters don't need to be specified in the same order as they appear in the query. In a lot of cases, where parameter arrays and/or the query are generated dynamically, this is an extremely valuable feature.

Comment: I particularly hate counting `?`'s or having to reorder my parameters when I edit my SQL. Let's say that readability is subjective and we'll all be happy.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario when you have too much ?s to count - it's time to use some helper function to build SQL.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario when you have too much of *anything* repeated in your code, it's time to use some automation to let a program iterate all the repetitions for you.